# Haskell accesing the sublist while filtering a list of a list

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and try to accomplish the following:

```
filter (((!!) subList (fromJust (elemIndex String [String]))) == String) [[string]]
```

I replaced the names with their types to make it easier to read. The problem is that i can't do subList, but the (!!) takes a list as argument. So how would i go about writing this?

edit:

I wrote the filtering condition seperately, which works, but the problem is still the same:

```
findGood :: [String] -> String -> [String] -> String -> Bool
```

but i still need to fill in all the values, though the first [String] is the sublist. All the other values can be entered..

Edit:

I solved it, what i needed to do was put the [String] last, and then i could leave it out in the filter

So

```
findGood :: String -> [String] -> String -> [String] -> Bool
            filter (findGood a b c) [[String]]
```

Thats what works, and thats what I wanted. (not needing the D)

Comment: My guess is this will become easier if you take out the function you want to filter with and write it separately.  But it would be easier to understand what you're doing if you give us some example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could explain in words what you were trying to do here.

Comment: Please instead of posting some invalid code fragment, first explain *what* you aim to accomplish. What problem do you want to solve with this `filter`?

Comment: I have a table, which is a list of lists of strings. The top of the table has names. So for instance, i want to only show all the rows where money is higher than 500, the code would search the location of money in top list, and then would, for every row, check if the value on that spot is higher than 500 and if not, not show the row

So for each "Sublist" i want to check if a word on a certain index is equal to another word, but to check that i need the sublist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're wanting to compare money and check `money > 500` it makes much more sense to store it as an `Int` not a `String`. Furthermore I would say storing each entry as a tuple and having a list of tuples makes more sense than using a list of lists (this is also required for the Int implementation of money as you can't have a list of different types of lists).

So the table would have type `[(String, Int)]`.

`filter` goes through the list and checks each element against a condition. In this case the condition is so simple I wouldn't bother making it it's own function (unless you need to reuse it in lots of places).

When given a pair of type `(String, Int)` we just want to check if that second value is > 500. So the condition is simply `snd row > 500` where row is the tuple we were given representing a row in the table.

This leaves us with:
`filter (\row -> snd row > 500) table`

Testing on `[("Geoff", 600), ("Bill", 700), ("Bill Jr.", 10)]` this gives `[("Geoff", 600), ("Bill", 700)]` as expected.

Comment: Thanks, for the described scenario it works indeed, but i needed a solution to a more abstract problem. Specificaly what i did in my second edit.

Comment: @BaasBartMans You're welcome, next time it would probably help if you described the abstract problem in the question. Nobody can help you if they don't know what the problem is.